# R plotting why not starting from (0,0)?

Tags: r, plot

I'm new to R programming and graphics. I'm trying to draw a graph but the (0,0) point is not at the right place. Can someone please tell me how to fix it? Thanks.
[image]

Here's my code:

```
layout(matrix(c(0,0,0,0,0,
                0,1,3,2,0,
                0,0,0,0,0), nc = 5, byrow = TRUE),
       widths = c(lcm(2), 1, lcm(2), 1, lcm(2)),
       heights = c(lcm(2), 1, lcm(2)))
layout.show(3)
box("outer", lty = "dotted")
plot.new()
plot.window(xlim=c(-200,0),ylim=c(0,21))
box()
axis(1)
axis(4)
rect(-113,0,0,1,col='cyan')
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

you can go to see `'xaxs'` in `?par`

Comment: thanks, I was able to fix it by using `par(xaxs='i',yaxs='i')`